# how to omit a time period from the x-axis in microsoft chart control

Tags: c#, microsoft-chart-controls

I am developing a Windows Application in Visual Studio, coding in c#, .Net Framework 4.

On a chart, I plot the intraday time series of prices for a stock.  When I plot a single day, it works fine.  However, when I plot multiple days, there is a huge gap between the time the market closes one day and opens the next day.  The series points do not include any data outside of market hours. i.e. the last data point on 8/10/2011 and the first data point on 8/11/2011 are as follows:

8/10/2011 3:59 PM, $59.00

8/11/2011 9:30 PM, $59.25

I would like to omit that empty time period.  Any help greatly appreciated.

(sorry, can't post an image of the chart because don't have a 10 reputation, but hopefully you can use your imagination!)

Comment: My mistake- I did not look at your tags closely enough and thought you were using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel within C# to create graphs in Excel.  Sorry- I know nothing about Microsoft-Chart-Controls.

Comment: I would recommend to look at the third party controls with calendar feature that supports skipping date/time ranges from the X axis. Please refer to this [link](http://helpdotnetvision.nevron.com/UsersGuide_Axes_Scale_ScaleConfigurators_Overview.html) for extended information.